# How do I read a CSV file by selecting the desired column using shell script?

Tags: shell, csv, merge, scripting

I have several CSV files I need to merge into a single file.

Luckily, there is primary key used across all files. Based on the primary key, I need to read the date from several files on selected columns.

How can I get started by reading in data based on the column name?

I think the next big task would be how to read multiple files like an access tables querying on the primary key that is present across each file.

```
H1,Name, DOB,…. static information (columns from the csv 1 file)
SASH1,Auth#,State,Status,…. (columns from the csv 2 file)
SPLI,RequestedFromDate,Type,ServiceType,….. (columns from the csv 3 file)
CRLI,DateofReview,ReviewedBy,CriteriaMet,…. (columns from the csv 4 file)
ARLI,DateofReview,CriteriaMet,CriteriaSource,…. (columns from the csv 4 file)
```

```
output - 
H1,Name, DOB,….
SASH1,**OP0619**,NY,VOID ….. One-One - Main csv with primary key (first record)
SPLI,10/1/2019,DFG,Full,….. One-many records from file2 match primary key
SPLI,10/3/2019,DFG,Full,….. One-many records from file2 match primary key
SPLI,10/3/2019,DFG,Full,….. One-many records from file2 match primary key
CRLI,11/22/2019,Kim,Yes,….. One-many records from file3 match primary key
CRLI,11/23/2019,Jon,Yes,….. One-many records from file3 match primary key
.
.
H1,Name, DOB,…. 
SASH1,OP0586,NY,VOID ….. One-One Main csv with primary key (second record)
SPLI,1/1/2019,DE,Level2,….. One-many records from file2 match primary key
SPLI,1/3/2019,DFG,Full,….. One-many  records from file2 match primary key
SPLI,1/3/2019,DFG,Full,….. One-many  records from file2 match primary key
CRLI,5/22/2019,John,Yes,….. One-many records from file3 match primary key
CRLI,3/23/2019,Bill,Yes,….. One-many records from file3 match primary key
```

And so on and so on ….

Comment: Do you want to read csv file and get a particular column or is it something else ?

Comment: yes I would like to read each csv file in the folder and get a particular column data. Each record shares the same primary key. So my goal is to select all record from each csv file that correspond to the primary selected from the parent csv. Hopefully I am explaining clearly my intention. It is a bit challenging and above my experience level

Comment: Your question is unclear. (1) do you have a single file that contains the names of the columns you want to merge from `csv1..4`? Or, do you want to merge all columns from `csv1..4`? (2) What is the format of each of the `csv1..4` files? (a) do they have a single heading row, or (b) are there multiple heading rows? (3) Is the order of the merged columns the original order they were in the original `csv1..4`? All matter. Next, what have you tried? `awk` will be the proper tool or simply `paste` may work in your case.

Comment: My apologies, I am new to this. I am looking for a starting point cause I have no clue how to being this project. All the files are comma delimited csv file. I have sample data that might make things clearer. How do you upload files to the question area? So there is one csv file with one-one records. Based on this file I would like to merge record from other files sharing the same primary key. All files have header rows. There is only selected amount of columns I need from all files. So I will need to be able to identify which column data is being printed to the merge file.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding on you problem , I have reached on below solution.

here is my use case:-

declared 3 variables(later you can replace them with your files) and performed below query on the same

```
var=abc,bcd,xyz,pqm
var2=qwe,asd,zxc,rty
var3=poi,lkj,mnb,ghj

echo "`echo $var|awk -F"," '{print $1}'`,`echo $var2|awk -F"," '{print $2}'`,`echo $var3|awk -F"," '{print $3}'`"
```

and the output is:-

```
abc,asd,mnb
```

Comment: Thank you Ankush. I see your output and it looks to be a good start. I added my csv file to the script it is only displaying the file name. Authorization.csv,,

Comment: may i know the required output and command/script you are running

Comment: I am using shell script. I am researching awk to accomplish the task. The desired outcome would look some like this. This tool does not allow me to format the output for display. I show it in the original question.